# Moving files into existing subfolders based on part of the filename using switch statement for matching?

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

I've got a folder that gets filled with a bunch of log files that need to be moved into sub-folders every so often.  For example, I need to get the following files into the directories at the arrow.

SOME_FILE_341213.txt --> SMPROD 
SOME_FILE_341242.txt --> SMPROD 
OTHER_FILE_13423.log --> SSBRPRD 
ALTER_FILE_13423.log --> SSBRPRD 
geofile12321 --> REGIONPROD

I've seen lots of solutions that will parse out part of a file name and move it into a directory containing that parse of the file name.  In my case, the destination directories will not really match up to a parsed part of the file names.  I was thinking I could use a switch statement to match the first 4 or 5 letters to cases that would move files into the appropriate directories but I'm not sure that's the most efficient way to go about it.  I would have about 25 cases to match to. For files that didn't match any case I would leave them where they are. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the switch statement in a for-each loop. Something like this:

```
$Files = Dir c:\test

foreach ($file in $files) {
    switch ($file.ToString().Substring(0,2)) {
        "te" {Write-Host "te"; break}
        "li" {Write-Host "li"; break}
        "ts" {Write-Host "ts"; break}

    } #End switch
} #End foreach
```

On the `substring(x,y)` command, the overload is:

1. x = starting character
2. y = number of characters to pull

Obviously replace  the `write-host` with what you actually want to do.  The switch statement can span multiple lines.  Don't forget the `break` at the end, so you don't go through all 25 options for every file.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with a switch. Personally for something like this I would prefer a hashtable. Something like:

```
$dirInfo = @{'SOME' = 'SMPROD';
             'OTHE' = 'SSBRPRD';
             'ALTE' = 'SSBRPRD';
             'GEOF' = 'REGIONPROD'
            }

$prefix = $file.Name.Substring(0,4).ToUpper()
if($dirInfo.ContainsKey($prefix)){
    $moveDir = 'C:\PATH\TO\SOMEFOLDER\{0}' -f $dirInfo[$prefix]
    Move-Item $file $moveDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hard code a switch statement I would probably build a hashtable from a text file containing key value pairs; this would mean that anyone not familiar with Powershell could administer the filename / destination relationships.  I'm not sure this would be more efficient but it means you're not having to update the script if and when the filenames or destinations change.

Here's a quick example... it doesn't do any copying but demonstrates the method:

```
$hashData = ConvertFrom-StringData ([IO.File]::ReadAllText("c:\temp\_sotemp\_hash\hashfile.txt"))
$directory = 'C:\Temp\_sotemp'
Get-ChildItem $directory |  
    where {!($_.PsIsContainer)} | 
    Foreach-Object {
    Foreach ($key in $hashData.GetEnumerator()){ 
        if ($_.name.substring(0,7) -eq $key.Name){
        Write-Host $_.fullname " will be copied to: " $key.Value
        }
    }
}
```

A couple of things to note.  Firstly, don't use the Get-Content CMDLet to read the text file containing the key value pairs as it can do some strange things to hashtables - you can end up with a hash of hashes!  Secondly the substring method will throw an error if you pass a filename with less than 7 characters - you may want to handle this?

Here's the text file contents:

```
geofile=c:\\temp\\_sotemp\\REGIONPROD
other_f=c:\\temp\\_sotemp\\SSBRPRD
alter_f=c:\\temp\\_sotemp\\SSBRPRD
some_fi=c:\\temp\\_sotemp\\SMPROD
```

Answer (score 0):

Another switch version.

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp" | foreach {
   switch -regex ($_.Name) {
      "^g.+" { write-output "$_.Name --> REGIONPROD"; break }
      "^S.+" { write-output "$_.Name  --> SMPROD" ; break }
      "^[O|A].+" { write-output "$_.Name  --> SSBRPRD" ; break }
   }
}
```

And another hash version with target directories from a file.

```
$hash = @{}
Get-Content C:\temp\hashData.txt | foreach { if ($_ -notmatch  "^$") {
   $fn, $dn = $_.split("|"); $hash.Add($fn, $dn) }
}

Get-ChildItem "C:\temp" | foreach {
   $fn = $_.Name.Substring(0,2)
   Write-Host "$_.Name   --> "  $hash.Item($fn)
}
```

Here is the hashData.txt I used for testing.

```
So|SMPROD 
Ot|SSBRPRD 
Al|SSBRPRD 
Ge|REGIONPROD
```

Comment: Is it possible to use wildcard characters within the hashtable?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're after now.  Is it a change to the original question? If so some examples of what you want might help.

Comment: What I've realized is that because of some of the naming conventions for the files in the folder, I'll have to match for 9 characters in the hash table.  However, while most of the files have 9 static characters I can use to match some of them don't.  For example, one of my cases is 'sorainf_a|ADMINASSIGNPROD' this case works fine.  But I'll need another that is 'SRRPREL_*|SSBPROD' with the "*" being a place holder for a wildcard character.

Comment: In that case you might do better with the "switch -regex" option.